# Git reset hard not showing changes when pushed

Tags: git, github

I want to undo a few commits.

So locally I do

```
$ (develop) git checkout -b a-new-branch
$ (a-new-branch) git reset --hard a-good-commit
$ (a-new-branch) git push origin a-new-branch
```

But when (on `GitHub`) I try to perform a PR `develop <-- a new branch`

it shows no changes!

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're asking git to put on `develop` everything `a new branch` has which `develop` does not have.

But no commit fits that definition, since `a new branch` has all the same commits, minus some.

To achieve what you want, very broadly, you'd have to either reset develop itself and push it with force (if you're alone on the branch), or revert each unwanted commit on `develop`.